# Dimension increasing (or decreasing) operator

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, operator-theory

I am looking for a linear(?) dimension increasing operator $\odot$ that would work as follows

For $ x \in \mathbb{R^n}$

$(F \odot x) \in \mathbb{R}^{(n+1)}$

$F \odot (F \odot x) \in \mathbb{R}^{(n+2)}$

$F \odot (F \odot (F \odot x)) \in \mathbb{R}^{(n+3)}$ and so on...

Intuition would say $F$ is another matrix, but no constraints on the form of $F$ or what the "values" of $x$ are in the increased dimensions. The only real constraint would be on the conservation of the recursive form.
I am not very fluent with linear algebraic tricks, thanks for any help.

Comment: There is no one matrix that does this by the usual association of matrices with linear maps. You could interpret an infinitely large matrix as doing something like this, but I'm not sure if that's a useful formalism in your case

Comment: Thanks Ben, I keep coming back to infinite dimensional forms which is what I am trying to avoid in the first place. I was hoping for some other trick or form akin the Kronecker product... The idea/concept is seemingly so simple (one step dimension growth iteration),  but yet so far out of reach so far.

Comment: Maybe it makes sense to have a matrix for each dimension $n$.

Comment: YES! There is the variable $F(k)$ form idea I toyed around with non-linear forms, $F(1)\odot    x \in \mathbb{R^{(n+1)}}$ and $F(2) \odot (F(1)\odot    x) \in \mathbb{R^{(n+2)}}$ but then I am stuck in coming up with the actual form for the iteration of $F(k+1)$ in terms of $F(k)$

Comment: Can you say concretely what $F(k)\odot x$ looks like, say for $k = 2,3$?

Comment: Vaguely related: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creation_and_annihilation_operators

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you are asking, but again constraints are very relaxed with no concrete structure at the moment but just increase in dimensions any way possible. Here is one trivial possibility: For $k=1, F(1): (n+1) \times n$ matrix  
 
For $k=1, F(2): (n+2) \times (n+1) $ matrix 

For $k=1, F(3): (n+3) \times (n+2)$ matrix

But no idea how how to iterate (imagine the generative form for) : $F(k+1)$ from $F(k)$

Comment: @BrianS. So for example, what about something like $F \odot (x_1,\dots,x_n) = (x_1,\dots,x_n,0)$?

Comment: Yes, I think that should work nicely (assuming I will find another transform to easily transform the 0 component to any other number - once you are in the fixed dimensional paradigm everything is easier)